# How to create extended type

Tags: go

I see that it's possible to extend imported packages, for example to add new methods.

However, I try this to create a new instance of my own struct:

```
package main

import (
    "github.com/intdxdt/rtree"
)

type RTree struct {
    rtree.RTree
}

func NewRTree(nodeCap ...int) *RTree {
    return rtree.NewRTree(nodeCap...)
}
```

I saw similar example at other question. But I get an error: **cannot use rtree.NewRTree(nodeCap...) (type *rtree.RTree) as type *RTree in return argument**.

The question is - how do I init and use my own struct with my own methods and all imported methods/fields included?

Comment: There is no inheritance in Go and the only polymorphism is using interfaces. You cannot "extend" types in the OOP sense.

Comment: @Adrian, internet says I can, it doesn't matter OOP sense or something similar. I use word "extend" because it's pretty close to the needed goal

Comment: If you change your struct to use a pointer, `&RTree{rtree.NewRTree(nodeCap...)}` should work.

Comment: "internet" is pretty vague, but anything you saw that claims you can "extend" a type in Go is incorrect. You cannot. You can embed types, you cannot extend them.

Comment: @Leon no, it will still be invalid. The code is still attempting to return an `rtree.RTree` when the function signature says it returns a `main.RTree`.

Comment: @Adrian, ok, but in my case how do I use my own struct **RTree** with all methods from the imported package? + my own methods. First question is how do I init it at least?

Comment: Learning the syntax of Go is best done by taking the Tour of Go. So is not the right place.

Comment: You could initialize it as `return &RTree{ *(retree.NewRTree(nodeCap...)) }` with your existing code. It would expose all methods of `rtree.RTree` as well. However, you could not pass it to any function expecting a parameter of type `rtree.RTree`.

Comment: @Adrian, thanks! Now `NewRTree` is usable as expected

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Always remember, Go doesn't support `inheritance`. It supports `composition`.

You may `call` it inheritance, as far as it helps you to logically map between other OOP languages, and Go. Rule of thumb, whenever something doesn't work the way it works in `OOP` world, think in terms of composition.

But when it comes to writing actual code, always remember that there is no `is a` relationship in composition, and it's always `has a`, even if it seems otherwise, because of the fact that you can actually access the member variables and methods of the `composed/embedded`(still, not inherited) struct. You can even `override` the method, if you declare the same with the new struct. Here's another catch - You still won't be able to access un-exposed (close to `protected` from Java-world) variables and functions of a struct in another package, as it seems in your case.

But, your type `RTree` `has` `rtree.RTree`, but is never going to be a `rtree.RTree`, and will always be a different type for the compiler.

```
package main

import (
    "github.com/intdxdt/rtree"
)

type RTree struct {
    rtree.RTree
}

func NewRTree(nodeCap ...int) *RTree {
    return &RTree{
        RTree: *rtree.NewRTree(nodeCap...),
    }
}
```

On a separate node, unless you have more parameters to add, why not use `rtree.RTree` directly? Composing it, will give you all the methods of the enclosing type, but you can't pass it to any function that expects the enclosing type. Good news is, you will implicitly satisfy the interfaces that enclosing type satisfies, and hence you can pass it to functions that accept those interfaces.

Comment: I just need to override a method. And Yes.. I see now that not exposed methods are not available, need to think about a workaround

Comment: Well, not sure what you are trying to do. But if a package hasn't made a method exposed, most probably they don't want you using it. There must be some other way. Otherwise, the library needs more functionalities.

Comment: Also remember when you do this that the “inner” RTree object doesn’t know anything about the object in which it’s contained.  If you’ve “overridden” some method, and call some other unmodified method which calls the thing you think you’re overriding, it will see the unmodified method in the contained object, not anything in the wrapper.

Comment: @DavidMaze Good one, I had learnt it the hard way.

Some related examples, of calling both over-ridden and over-riding methods(& accessing variables)
https://play.golang.org/p/RegLWdmcce7

Comment: small fix, there should be `return &RTree{ *retree.NewRTree(nodeCap...) }` - with a `*` as imported function returns a pointer

Comment: Updated it, to deference the pointer returned by rtee.NewRTree()